# Create local virt-manager storage pool

Tags: permissions, virtualization

I want to create a **storage pool** for virt-manager's qcow2 images **in my home directory** but I get a strange error:

`Error creating pool: Could not define storage pool: XML error: name /home/matthias/virtual-guests/virt-manager cannot contain '/'`

[image: Error creating pool]

### questions

- Is it even possible to have the storage pool in my home directory?
- Do I need special permissions for virt-manager to access the directory?

### full error traceback

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createpool.py", line 442, in _async_pool_create
    poolobj = self._pool.install(create=True, meter=meter, build=build)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/storage.py", line 531, in install
    raise RuntimeError(_("Could not define storage pool: %s") % str(e))
RuntimeErError creating pool: Could not define storage poror: Could not define storage pool: XML error: name /home/matthias/virtual-guests/virt-manager cannot contain '/'`

Answer (score 2):

You can create pools, but there are a few things to consider.

1. The "name" really has to be without a set of special characters, like '/'. If you want to create a /tmp/test pool you might name it "*test*" (*on step 1 of 2*) and give it the path "*/tmp/test*" (*on step 2 of 2*) and it will work.
2. apparmor will stop you if you go too uncommon
   There is a limited set of paths that are allowed by default, if you go 
   out of these at some point *virt-aa-helper* will no more able to access the files. But that would be needed so that it can allow the access for the per-guest custom profile. See the existing rules in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libvirt.virt-aa-helper` and add custom ones via `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.lib.libvirt.virt-aa-helper`
   See /etc/apparmor.d/local/README for more on this.
3. Some pool types are yet unable to be handled by apparmor. The default pool type of virt-manager will be "*dir*" and that will be fine. But there are more advanced types like "*lvm groups*", for those types apparmor rules can not be created for the guest on the fly ([see bug on this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1677398)), in these cases you'll need to allow the extra paths you need via changing `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a pool for your home directory. You probably tried to create a pool named "/home/matthias/virtual-guests/virt-manager" which contains the "/" symbols. In the future, when creating a pool, enter a name without the "/" symbol.

You may need to create a QCOW2 file (disk image file) on another partition in the future, see the STEPS from this [GUIDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/1456791/1598538).
Also You may find useful this [GUIDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/1410487/1598538).

Answer (score 1):

### Creating a qcow2 disk image file on another partition

This guide was tested on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, 22.10, 23.04, 23.10.

#### Automatically linking a directory to a block (automatic partition mounting)

1. Make new directories

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/username
$ sudo mkdir /media/username/Shared
$ sudo mkdir /media/username/Shared/kvm
```

***Important!** Directory name kvm with lower case letters.*

2. Run blkid command to display information about available block devices. You will need universally unique identifier (UUID)

```
$ sudo blkid
```

The result should look something like:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="azazazaz-azaz-azaz-azaz-azazazazazaz" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Ubuntu" PARTUUID="a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Shared" UUID="abababab-abab-abab-abab-abababababab" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Shared" PARTUUID="a2a2a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2-a2a2a2a2a2a2"
```

3. Edit the fstab file.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the following two lines with the correct UUID in fstab file:

```
# Shared
UUID=abababab-abab-abab-abab-abababababab       /media/username/Shared        ext4    defaults        0       2
```

The end result should look something like:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=azazazaz-azaz-azaz-azaz-azazazazazaz /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# Shared
UUID=abababab-abab-abab-abab-abababababab       /media/username/Shared        ext4    defaults        0       2
```

4. Run `mount -a` command

```
$ sudo mount -a
```

*Possible issues:*

1. *The emulator may not have search permissions for the path
   '/media/username/Shared/kvm/Disk.qcow2'*
2. *Error starting domain: Cannot access storage file
   '/media/username/Shared/kvm/Disk.qcow2' (as uid:10101, gid:101):
   Permission denied*

5. Fix permission issues

```
$ sudo chown root:root '/media'
$ sudo chmod 775 '/media'

$ sudo chown root:root '/media/username'
$ sudo chmod 775 '/media/username'

$ sudo chown username:username '/media/username/Shared'
$ sudo chmod 775 '/media/username/Shared'

$ sudo chown username:username '/media/username/Shared/kvm'
$ sudo chmod 777 '/media/username/Shared/kvm'
```

#### Changing the default storage pool for libvirt

6. List the current pools

```
$ virsh pool-list
```

You should get the following text:

```
Name                 State      Autostart 
-------------------------------------------
default              active     yes
```

7. Destroy the default pool.

```
$ virsh pool-destroy default
```

You should get the following text: Pool default destroyed

8. Undefine the pool

```
$ virsh pool-undefine default
```

You should get the following text: Pool default has been undefined

9. Define a new pool named "default"

```
$ virsh pool-define-as --name default --type dir --target /media/username/Shared/kvm
```

You should get the following text: Pool default defined

10. Set the pool to start when the libvirt daemons start

```
$ virsh pool-autostart default
```

You should get the following text: Pool default marked as autostarted

11. Start the pool

```
$ virsh pool-start default
```

You should get the following text: Pool default started

12. Check the state of the pool

```
$ virsh pool-list
```

You should get the following text:

```
Name                 State      Autostart 
-------------------------------------------
default              active     yes
```

*Now, when creating virtual machines, Virtual Machine Manager will save qcow2 files to the /media/username/Shared/kvm directory.*

#### Creating a new guest machine or qcow2 file

13. Run virt-manager

```
$ virt-manager
```

14. Create a disk image for the virtual machine or create a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a mistake - not particulary obvious. I was trying to create storage pool in directory, so `dir:Filesystem Directory`

There are 2 steps:

1. You specify `type` and `name`, but here `name` **isn't path**. Example: `test`
2. Next step, `Target Path`, this will give you suggested path `/var/lib/libvirt/images/**test**. Simple **change**`/var/lib/libvirt/images`to whatever you want. Example:`/libvirt-images-pool2/`(which will result in`/libvirt-images-pool2/test```

Note: you might need to fiddle with ownership and permission, but I think libvirt fixes them once you click finish.

Hope it will help somebody.