# libvirt tools:sudo or not?

Tags: 22.04, virt-manager

What are the effects for using sudo for libvirt commands such as virt-manager/virsh? Will it affect something later when using the created VMs and regret not using it before?

I'm trying to use them without sudo (don't use root when you can ) and everything is fine. (Except for using bridged network - BTW not sure whether the problem is indeed sudo related at all)

But many articles such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406888/ubuntu-22-04-gpu-passthrough-qemu) use sudo in many cases, why?

Comment: I do not prefix my virsh commands with sudo, and have never had a problem. I only ever use a bridged network.